# How can I create a timeline with equal spacing between elements whilst maintaining full width of container?

Tags: html, css, django

**Issue Description**

I have created a timeline within a kanban item. The timeline design is exactly what I want but I have an issue with spacing between the timeline elements. I require the timeline to cover the full width of the container with first and last positioned at the very start and end of container but with equal distances between each element.

So instead of :
`O---O--O--O---O`

and more like:
`O--O--O--O--O`

But still maintain full width of the container.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cn9m0wfz/5/

**CSS**

```css
.kanban-booking-item .mini-timeline-item {
    padding:0;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

.kanban-booking-item .mini-timeline-item .item-container {
    background-color:rgb(209, 209, 209);
    height:15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius:10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.kanban-booking-item .mini-timeline-item .item {
    background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height:9px;
    width: 9px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:3px;
}


.kanban-booking-item .mini-timeline-item .pipe {
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
    height:3px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:3px;
    position:absolute;
    top:3px;
}


.kanban-booking-item .mini-timeline-item .pipe.pipe-left {
    left: -16px;
}

.kanban-booking-item .mini-timeline-item .pipe.pipe-right {
    right: -16px;
}

.kanban-booking-item .mini-timeline-item .pipe.pipe-centre-right {
    right: -9px;
    width: 50%;
}

.kanban-booking-item .mini-timeline-item .pipe.pipe-centre-left {
    left: -9px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="kanban-booking-item" style="padding: 0px 40px 8px 10px">
    <div class="content row" style="padding: 0 15px;">
        <div class="mini-timeline-item col" style="justify-content:flex-start;">
            <div class="item-container">
                <div class="item">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pipe pipe-right">       
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="mini-timeline-item col" style="justify-content:center;">
            <div class="pipe pipe-centre-left">
            </div>
            <div class="item-container">
                <div class="item">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pipe pipe-centre-right">
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="mini-timeline-item col" style="justify-content:center;">
             <div class="pipe pipe-centre-left">
             </div>
             <div class="item-container">
                <div class="item">
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="pipe pipe-centre-right">
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mini-timeline-item col" style="justify-content:center;">
            <div class="pipe pipe-centre-left Not-Started">
            </div>
            <div class="item-container">
                <div class="item Not-Started">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pipe pipe-centre-right">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mini-timeline-item col" style="justify-content:flex-end;">
            <div class="pipe pipe-left">
            </div>
            <div class="item-container">
                <div class="item">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Visual**

*Standard*

[image]

*Inspected*

[image]

> *Note: Timeline element count may vary so design must accommodate this (1+)*

> *Note: Responsiveness is not required as the kanban items are fixed widths*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I've since fixed the issue via the following:

- Added `justify-content-between` to container `row`
- Added fixed widths to columns to match that of elements
- Added `col` to fill gutters with timeline pipe
- Remove all previous connecting pipes

**HTML**

```html
<div class="kanban-booking-item" style="padding: 0px 40px 8px 10px">
        <div class="content row justify-content-between" style="padding: 0 15px;">
            <div class="mini-timeline-item col">
                <div class="item-container">
                    <div class="item Not-Started">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pipe-container col">
                <div class="pipe">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mini-timeline-item col">
                <div class="item-container">
                    <div class="item Not-Started">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pipe-container col">
                <div class="pipe">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mini-timeline-item col">
                <div class="item-container">
                    <div class="item Not-Started">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pipe-container col">
                <div class="pipe">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mini-timeline-item col">
                <div class="item-container">
                    <div class="item Not-Started">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pipe-container col">
                <div class="pipe">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mini-timeline-item col">
                <div class="item-container">
                    <div class="item Not-Started">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.kanban-booking-item .mini-timeline-item {
    padding:0;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 15px;
    max-width: 15px;
}

.kanban-booking-item .mini-timeline-item .item-container {
    background-color:rgb(209, 209, 209);
    height:15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius:10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.kanban-booking-item .mini-timeline-item .item {
    background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height:9px;
    width: 9px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:3px;
}

.kanban-booking-item .pipe-container {
    padding:0;
}

.kanban-booking-item .pipe-container .pipe {
    height:3px;
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
```

**Finished Visual**

[image]